# C#10 How to get Console.WriteLine to work

Tags: c#

I created a new C#10 app through my terminal on a remote linux machine. I used this:

```
dotnet new console -o HelloWorld
```

When I `cd` into the folder and run `dotnet run`, nothing logs to the terminal. I am not using Visual Studio, just the command line. I've done this hundreds of times without issue. The code generated looks like this:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

My project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Har you install sdk

Comment: When I run `dotnet --version` I get `6.0.202`

Comment: Do you get any verbose output when you do `dotnet run -v diag` or `dotnet build -v diag`?

Comment: You can check for the sdk and runtimes installed with `dotnet --list-runtimes` and `dotnet --list-sdks`.

Comment: I ran `dotnet run -v diag` and got a bunch of output but at the end there were 0 errors and 0 warnings. I also got no errors or warnings when I ran `dotnet --list-runtimes`. Is there some part of this output I should be looking at?

Comment: Does Debug.WriteLine() show anything?

Comment: `Dubug.WriteLine("Hello")` throws this error: ` The name Debug does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Does `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("a.txt","a.txt")` create a file containing `a.txt` called `a.txt`? (Trying to find out if it's output being redirected or app not running at all)

Comment: I added `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("a.txt","a.txt")` to my script and no files were created.

Comment: I downgraded from .net 6.0 to 3.1. Then built a new console app again and it builds but does not write anything to the console.

Comment: for some reason, I feel your issue is not related to dotnet, but more to your system environment

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled .NET entirely and reinstalled and it solved the issue.